# GAE tutorial issue. No entity

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm new to the GAE and I'm trying too hard not to ask this question but I have run into this problem and I can't figure it out.

when I run the MobileAssistant-AppEngine as a web application on the`localhost:8888/_ah/admin`

I can't seem to find any entity "CheckIn" in there. it just show me an empty list in the entity list.

I have already read couple of questions in here that look the same but no good

[Unable to generate cloud endpoint class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407046/unable-to-generate-cloud-endpoint-class)

Comment: How did you declare your CheckIn class? Can you post it?

Comment: I tried both '@PersistenceCapable' & '@Entity' but nothing